How to create a list of lists based on a dataframe in R?
Good day! I have this dataframe as an example:
year<-rep(2000:2002,times=3)
month<-rep(1:3,times=1,each=3)
x<-c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45)

df<-cbind(year,month,x)


As shown in the photo below, I would like to create a list by month and then within that list is a list by year. I also wish x to repeat at a certain length. May I humbly ask how can I recreate this on R?

Thank you very much!
I tried to use the map and lapply function but they are not working.

You can try using split() twice, first by month, then iterate over the result and split by year while replicating x to the desired length:
res <- lapply(split(df, ~ month), \(x) split(rep(x$x, 4), x$year)) 

str(res)

List of 3
 $ 1:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
  ..$ 2001: num [1:4] 10 10 10 10
  ..$ 2002: num [1:4] 15 15 15 15
 $ 2:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:4] 20 20 20 20
  ..$ 2001: num [1:4] 25 25 25 25
  ..$ 2002: num [1:4] 30 30 30 30
 $ 3:List of 3
  ..$ 2000: num [1:4] 35 35 35 35
  ..$ 2001: num [1:4] 40 40 40 40
  ..$ 2002: num [1:4] 45 45 45 45


This works!!!! thank you very much!!!! However, when I tried to subtract two lists of similar structure, it's giving me this error: non-numeric argument to binary operator May I ask if there is any way to solve this? Thank youuu!

@min - It would be best to post a new question and include your code that doesn't work and the expected outcome.

Are you looking for this?
> (l <- list(month1=lapply(1:3 |> setNames(paste0('year', 1:3)), \(x) rep_len(5*x, 4)),
+           month2=lapply(4:6 |> setNames(paste0('year', 4:6)), \(x) rep_len(5*x, 4)),
+           month3=lapply(7:9 |> setNames(paste0('year', 7:9)), \(x) rep_len(5*x, 4))
+ ))
$month1
$month1$year1
[1] 5 5 5 5

$month1$year2
[1] 10 10 10 10

$month1$year3
[1] 15 15 15 15


$month2
$month2$year4
[1] 20 20 20 20

$month2$year5
[1] 25 25 25 25

$month2$year6
[1] 30 30 30 30


$month3
$month3$year7
[1] 35 35 35 35

$month3$year8
[1] 40 40 40 40

$month3$year9
[1] 45 45 45 45


> str(l)
List of 3
 $ month1:List of 3
  ..$ year1: num [1:4] 5 5 5 5
  ..$ year2: num [1:4] 10 10 10 10
  ..$ year3: num [1:4] 15 15 15 15
 $ month2:List of 3
  ..$ year4: num [1:4] 20 20 20 20
  ..$ year5: num [1:4] 25 25 25 25
  ..$ year6: num [1:4] 30 30 30 30
 $ month3:List of 3
  ..$ year7: num [1:4] 35 35 35 35
  ..$ year8: num [1:4] 40 40 40 40
  ..$ year9: num [1:4] 45 45 45 45

Or more general:
> n_y <- 2; n_m <- 4; n <- 6
> lapply(setNames(seq_len(n_m), paste0("month", seq_len(n_m))),
+        \(y) lapply(setNames(seq_len(n_y)*y, paste0("year", seq_len(n_y))), 
+                    \(x) rep_len(5*x, n)))
$month1
$month1$year1
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5

$month1$year2
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10


$month2
$month2$year1
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10

$month2$year2
[1] 20 20 20 20 20 20


$month3
$month3$year1
[1] 15 15 15 15 15 15

$month3$year2
[1] 30 30 30 30 30 30


$month4
$month4$year1
[1] 20 20 20 20 20 20

$month4$year2
[1] 40 40 40 40 40 40

